# How to find source of conversion?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have applied successfully tracking codes from different ad media (adwords, facebook, linked in etc) to our sales page completion page.

The problem is that, we cant explore from where did conversions pass through from Analytics.

We can see tracking codes working on each media separately, but it would be better if we could see a report in analytics. We have already generated (and have them working) goals in Analytics.

How can we find the source of every goal in it?
Do we need to make a custom report or something?

Any help is appreciated much since i am not so familiar with Analytics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can set the second dimension to referral or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Acquisition - All Traffic and select the goal from the drop down in the Conversions column.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow all the steps:

1. To track Adwords, you need to link cost-data from your Adwords account + make sure auto-tagging is enabled in your Adwords account.
2. For all other sources, you need to use the [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) to create a special link.
3. If you set things correctly, you should have different media set up as sources and further deep down is available via campaigns etc. You can see this data under the acquisition submenu on your left hand side.
4. If you want to create a report that does exactly what you want - go to customization (upper part of the page) => Create custom report => under dimensions select "source/medium", and under metrics, select everything that you want to see per marketing channel. I suggest adding: Sessions, Goals (select the specific goals that you care for), New users, Users and bounce rate.

I hope that helps.